# C# maths quiz with user choosen difficulty-level

Tags: c#, beginner, console, mathematics

I have built a maths project that asks the user an addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, power and square root questions based on the difficulty level they choose!

But I am trying to refactor the code so I don't repeat myself too many times.

Can anyone please help me make the code less repeatable?

Here is the code:

```
using System;

namespace mathstester
{
    class Program
    {
        enum UserDifficulty
        {
            Easy,
            Normal,
            Hard
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userDifficulty = "";
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What difficulty level would you like to do! Please type E for Easy, N for Normal and H for hard");
                userDifficulty = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            } while (userDifficulty != "E" && userDifficulty != "N" && userDifficulty != "H");

            int numberOfQuestions = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("How many questions would you like to answer? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfQuestions);
            } while (numberOfQuestions % 10 != 0);

            int numberOfQuestionsLeft = numberOfQuestions;
            Random random = new Random();
            int score = 0;

            while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
            {
                var operation = random.Next(1, 7);
                int number1 = 0;
                int number2 = 0;
                switch (userDifficulty)
                {
                    case "E":
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                number1 = random.Next(13);
                                number2 = random.Next(13);
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                    case "N":
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                number1 = random.Next(1, 10000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1, 1000);
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                    case "H":
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case 3:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                number1 = random.Next(1, 10000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1, 1000);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                number1 = random.Next(13);
                                number2 = random.Next(5);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                }

                if(operation == 1 && (userDifficulty == "E" || userDifficulty == "N"))
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} + {number2} =");
                    int correctAnswer = number1 + number2;
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 2 && (userDifficulty == "E" || userDifficulty == "N"))
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} - {number2} =");
                    int correctAnswer = number1 - number2;
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 3 && (userDifficulty == "E" || userDifficulty == "N" || userDifficulty == "H"))
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} * {number2} =");
                    int correctAnswer = number1 * number2;
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 4 && (userDifficulty == "N" || userDifficulty == "H") && (number1 > number2))
                {
                    Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is {number1} / {number2} =");
                    double correctAnswer = ((double)number1) / ((double)number2);
                    double roundedCorrectAnswer = Math.Round(correctAnswer);
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (roundedCorrectAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 5 && userDifficulty == "H")
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} ^ {number2} =");
                    double correctAnswer = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 6 && userDifficulty == "H")
                {
                    Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is √{number1} =");
                    double correctAnswer = Math.Sqrt(number1);
                    double roundedCorrectAnswer = Math.Round(correctAnswer);
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (roundedCorrectAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"You got a score of {score} out of {numberOfQuestions}");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider using classes more often.

For your current work, you need two classes (at least) to handle the application process. A class would be for holding the `Questions` and another class to hold the application logic.

```
// define the number of levels you need which would be used for random.
// so if the user chose Easy, this means it will pick from 1 to 3 MathOperation.
public enum UserDifficulty { Easy = 3, Normal = 4, Hard = 6 }

public enum MathOperation { Addition = 1, Subtraction = 2, Multiplication = 3, Division = 4, Power = 5, SquareRoot = 6 }

public class MathQuestions
{
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public MathOperation OperaionType { get; set; }
    public int LeftHand { get; set; }
    public int RightHand { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAnswer => Calculate();
    public int GivenAnswer { get; set; }

    public bool IsCorrect => CorrectAnswer == GivenAnswer;

    public int Calculate()
    {
        switch (OperaionType)
        {
            case MathOperation.Addition:
                return LeftHand + RightHand;
            case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                return LeftHand - RightHand;
            case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                return LeftHand * RightHand;
            case MathOperation.Division:
                return LeftHand / RightHand;
            case MathOperation.Power:
                return (int)Math.Pow(LeftHand, RightHand);
            case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                return (int)Math.Sqrt(LeftHand);
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public string GetOperationString()
    {
        switch (OperaionType)
        {
            case MathOperation.Addition:
                return $"{LeftHand} + {RightHand}";
            case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                return $"{LeftHand} - {RightHand}";
            case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                return $"{LeftHand} x {RightHand}";
            case MathOperation.Division:
                return $"{LeftHand} / {RightHand}";
            case MathOperation.Power:
                return $"{LeftHand} ^ {RightHand}";
            case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                return $"√{LeftHand}";
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

public class MathClass
{
    // you need two randoms, one for the questions, and ther other one for the operators
    // using one for each would avoid skipping the operator numbers and vise versa. 
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    private readonly Random randomOperator = new Random();

    private readonly List<MathQuestions> questions = new List<MathQuestions>();

    private int NumberOfQuestions { get; }

    private UserDifficulty Difficulty { get; }

    public MathClass(UserDifficulty difficulty, int numberOfQuestions)
    {
        Difficulty = difficulty;
        NumberOfQuestions = numberOfQuestions;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MathQuestions> GetQuestions()
    {
        var level = (int)Difficulty + 1;

        int operation;

        for (int x = 1; x <= NumberOfQuestions; x++)
        {
            operation = randomOperator.Next(1, level);

            var question = new MathQuestions
            {
                QuestionNumber = x,
                LeftHand = random.Next(1000),
                RightHand = random.Next(500),
                OperaionType = (MathOperation)operation

            };

            // Calculate the Correct Answer.
            question.Calculate();

            questions.Add(question);
        }

        return questions;
    }

}
```

then you can do this :

```
public static class Program
{    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //for the MathClass
        UserDifficulty difficulty = UserDifficulty.Normal;

        int numberOfQuestions = 0;

        int steps = 1; // number of process steps before getting the exam

        while (steps <= 2)
        {
            if(steps == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What difficulty level would you like to do! Please type E for Easy, N for Normal and H for hard");

                var userDifficultyStr = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();


                if (!new[] { "E", "N", "H" }.Contains(userDifficultyStr)) { continue; } // return to this step.

                switch (userDifficultyStr)
                {
                    case "E":
                        difficulty = UserDifficulty.Easy;
                        break;
                    case "N":
                        difficulty = UserDifficulty.Normal;
                        break;
                    case "H":
                        difficulty = UserDifficulty.Hard;
                        break;
                }

                //Go to the next Step
                steps++;
            }


            if(steps == 2)
            {
               Console.Write("How many questions would you like to answer? Please type a number divisible by 10!");

               if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfQuestions) || numberOfQuestions % 10 != 0) { continue; } // return to this step.

                // if all things okay break this loop 
                break;
            }
        }

        // Create the questions
        var questions = new MathClass(difficulty, numberOfQuestions).GetQuestions().ToList();// using Linq

        // Loop over them 
        foreach (var question in questions)
        {

            int answer;

            Console.Write($"What is {question.GetOperationString()} = ");

            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input, only integers are allowed. Try Again!");
            }

            // store the answer of this question 
            question.GivenAnswer = answer;

            if (answer != question.CorrectAnswer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
            }
        }


        var score = questions.Count(x => x.IsCorrect); // using Linq

        Console.WriteLine($"You got a score of {score} out of {questions.Count}");

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

if just want to make partial changes on the current loop you can do this :

```
// set the operation max value based on the given difficulty.
int operationMax = 0;

switch (userDifficulty)
{
    case "E":
        operationMax = 3;           
        break;
    case "N":
        operationMax = 4;           
        break;
    case "H":
        operationMax = 7;           
        break;                                          
}           

while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
{
    var operation = random.Next(1, operationMax);

    // make them all double 
    double number1 = 0;
    double number2 = 0;
    double correctAnswer; 
    double userAnswer; 

    // store the msg
    string msg = string.Empty;

    switch(operation)
    {
        case 1:
            number1 = random.Next(1000);
            number2 = random.Next(1000);
            correctAnswer = number1 + number2;
            msg = $"{number1} + {number2}";
            break;
        case 2:
            number1 = random.Next(1000);
            number2 = random.Next(1000);
            correctAnswer = number1 - number2;
            msg = $"{number1} - {number2}";
            break;      
        case 3:
            number1 = random.Next(13);
            number2 = random.Next(13);
            correctAnswer = number1 * number2;
            msg = $"{number1} x {number2}";
            break;
        case 4:
            number1 = random.Next(1, 10000);
            number2 = random.Next(1, number1 - 1);  // this would give smaller number than number1 
            correctAnswer = number1 / number2;
            msg = $"{number1} / {number2}";
            break;      
        case 5:
            number1 = random.Next(13);
            number2 = random.Next(5);   
            correctAnswer = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
            msg = $"{number1} ^ {number2}";
            break;              
        case 6:
            number1 = random.Next(1000);    
            correctAnswer = Math.Sqrt(number1);
            msg = $"√{number1}";
            break;                      
    }


    if(operation == 4 || operation == 6)
    {
        Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is {msg} =");  
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.Write($"What is {msg} =");
    }

    userAnswer = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    if (Math.Round(correctAnswer) == Math.Round(userAnswer))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
    }               

}

Console.WriteLine($"You got a score of {score} out of {numberOfQuestions}");
```

let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank You, But for now, I just want to make my code less repeatable without changing it much. For example, after the switch cases I made, there is an "if else-if" loop. Inside that loop, there is an "if-else" loop. How do I take that if-else loop out of the other loop so I do not write it so many times?

Comment: @crazydanyal1414 check the update

Answer (score 1):

I would create more classes:

An interface Operation with the functions:

- getQuestionString
- checkAnswer
  at the moment, you don't need this.
  Add this when you want to add questions with multiple possible answers eg. 3/4 and 6/8
- getAnswer
- next

checkAnswer takes a String: the one the user answered and return if it is the correct answer.

You then can create different subclasses: SumOperation, ProductOperation, SubtractOperation

You add a constructor asking for the `maximumNumber1` and `maximumNumber2`.
You could call those constructor straight from your program, but it would be even better if you created subclasses (eg. SimpleSumOperation, HardProductOperation) where you define these values.
This is necessary if you would have operations that takes more and/or other arguments.

When you add these operations to an array based upon the user choosen level, you can select a random value of this array call `next` on the question and you have your next question.

## factory

You could add even more classes...
If you remove next from you question and if the questions don't longer ask for a maxRand but for the specific values instead, you can do the exact same quiz twice.
This means you do need to create those operations.
You can do this yourself, by calling the constructors with the specific values, but you could also create a factory for each operation (eg. ProductOperationFactory).

This factory could take the difficulty and 
know about the random values for each difficulty, but you could also create a subclass for each factory (eg. SimpleSubtractFactory).
You can add these factories to an array, random select a factory and then create the question which you then ask.

This are all suggestions which you all can ignore if you want.
Using all of my suggestions would mean that instead of a class you get a big fat program which could be way to much for what you want.